# Having weird behavior with slice append

Tags: arrays, go, append, slice

Can someone explain to me why the value of temp decided to change on the last output line even temp is just a copy of list array?

```golang
func subsets(nums []int) [][]int {
    
    if len(nums) == 0 {
        return [][]int{[]int{}}
    }
    
    list := [][]int{[]int{nums[0]}}
    
    for _, n := range nums[1:]{
        list = append(list, []int{n})
        temp := list[:len(list)-1]
        fmt.Println(temp)
        for _, arr := range temp {
            arr = append(arr, n)
            list = append(list, arr)
        }
       
        fmt.Println(temp)
        fmt.Println("  ")
    }
    
    list = append(list, []int{})
    return list
    
}
```

```
output:
[[1]]
[[1]]
  
[[1] [2] [1 2]]
[[1] [2] [1 2]]
  
[[1] [2] [1 2] [3] [1 3] [2 3] [1 2 3]]
[[1] [2] [1 2] [3] [1 3] [2 3] [1 2 3]]
  
[[1] [2] [1 2] [3] [1 3] [2 3] [1 2 3] [4] [1 4] [2 4] [1 2 4] [3 4] [1 3 4] [2 3 4] [1 2 3 4]]
[[1] [2] [1 2] [3] [1 3] [2 3] [1 2 3] [4] [1 4] [2 4] [1 2 4] [3 4] [1 3 4] [2 3 4] [1 2 3 5]]
```

Comment: A copy of a slice still points to the same underlying array. Please read https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you're copying slice, not an array.
A slice is a descriptor of an array segment. It consists of a pointer to the array, the length of the segment, and its capacity (the maximum length of the segment).
It means, you're just creating a copy of slice's header. Underlying array is still shared.
https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro

Answer (score -3):

That's a very common issue with arrays and slices in Go (which differs from those in Python and JavaScript). You'll get used to it, already was also explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63475579/6553328).

---

Of course the Solution is also explained [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/solution/) which I guess you'd be aware of how it'd work.

---

This'll pass in Go using [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking) (a bit more simple to implement):

```
func subsets(nums []int) [][]int {
    subs := make([][]int, 0)
    backtrack(nums, 0, nil, &subs)
    return subs
}

func backtrack(nums []int, index int, sub []int, subs *[][]int) {
    if index == len(nums) {
        *subs = append(*subs, append([]int{}, sub...))
        return
    }

    backtrack(nums, index+1, sub, subs)
    backtrack(nums, index+1, append(sub, nums[index]), subs)
}
```

Similarly in Java,

```
public final class Solution {
    public static final List<List<Integer>> subsets(
        final int[] nums
    ) {
        List<List<Integer>> subs = new ArrayList<>();
        Arrays.sort(nums);
        backtrack(subs, new ArrayList<>(), nums, 0);
        return subs;
    }

    private static void backtrack(
        final List<List<Integer>> subs, 
        final List<Integer> sub, 
        final int[] nums, 
        final int start
    ) {
        subs.add(new ArrayList<>(sub));

        for (int index = start; index < nums.length; index++) {
            sub.add(nums[index]);
            backtrack(subs, sub, nums, index + 1);
            sub.remove(sub.size() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Iteratively, it would go (e.g., with C++):

```
// The following block might trivially improve the exec time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto __optimize__ = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(NULL);
    std::cout.tie(NULL);
    return 0;
}();


// Most of headers are already included;
// Can be removed;
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>


using ValueType = std::uint_fast16_t;

static const struct Solution {
    static const std::vector<std::vector<int>> subsets(
            const std::vector<int>& nums
    ) {
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> subs = {{}};
        ValueType subs_len;

        for (const auto& num : nums) {
            subs_len = std::size(subs);

            for (ValueType len = 0; len < subs_len; ++len) {
                subs.emplace_back(subs[len]);
                subs.back().emplace_back(num);
            }
        }

        return subs;
    }
};
```

Python also has a `combinations` tool that'd make it simple:

```
class Solution:
    def subsets(self, nums):
        return (tuple(j) for i in range(len(nums) + 1) for j in itertools.combinations(nums, i))
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/discuss) where you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including low-complexity algorithms and asymptotic [runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.

Comment: This answer does not explain *why* it works any better/differently than OP's code, so it does not serve to educate.

Comment: The issue is not with solving the challenge, it's about a peculiarity of go slices. This answer does not address that on any way.